# how to use a "-define" parameter of makefile in systemverilog testbench?

Tags: makefile, system-verilog, test-bench

Using the "make" command a define is done which looks like this:

```
make something -define "file=$(name)"
```

How can I use this define in my System verilog testbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert this to a `+define` switch when you invoke your compiler. For example, with modelsim/questa

```
vlog +define+file=\"$(file)\" .....
```

You may have to play around with how the quotes get through depending on the shell you are using.